# Resource cannot be found error when accessing a page in Docker Container

Tags: docker, containers

I created a asp.net webform project in Visual Studio with Docker support (Windows). When I run the project using Visual Studio page comes up as below
[image]

Visual Studio creates a docker image which I saw using command

```
docker images
```

See image below (webapplication3)
[image]

Now I run another instance of Image (webapplication3) by command

```
Docker run webapplication3:dev
```

I can see container running

```
Docker ps
```

see image below
[image]

But now when I access this new running container using ip http://172.17.183.118/PageA.aspx
it's not coming up, see image below (I have taken IP 172.17.183.118 from docker inspect command, so it is correct.
[image]

Can someone tell me why am I not able to view the page? Why is it saying "Resource cannot be found" error?

Comment: You could try to browse the address `http://localhost:80/PageA.aspx`.

Comment: I tried http://localhost:62774/PageA.aspx and it's working. Thanks Charles, for pointing in a relevant direction. I fail to understand ports. Now suppose I have to access this website from LAN or Internet, do I still need to use port number like 62774? How will I access this webpage from LAN or INTERNET?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run a Docker container default, the container will run with an internal IP address and an expose port map the local machine port, and the IP address will go out to the internet through the docker bridge which associated with the local machine network interface.

When you access the container inside the local machine, you just need to access the localhost with the port shows you. In your issue, you need to access the address `http://localhost:62774/PageA.aspx`. If you want to access the container from the Internet, you should access the IP address of your local machine with the port. For you, it means the address `http://your-local-machine-public-ip:62774/PageA.aspx`.

You can get more details from [Docker Network](https://docs.docker.com/network/). Also, I suggest you'd better run the container with the special port you plan just like `docker run -d -p nodePort:containerPort --name containerName yourImage`.